# Error when using UPDATE to populate a geometry column

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to update a column with new geometry but am getting

ERROR:  column "current_geom" is of type geometry but expression is of type boolean.

```
UPDATE this_table t1
    SET "current_geom" = ST_Intersects(t2.point_geom,t2.geom)
FROM other_table t2
WHERE t1.current_geom is null
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but not sure why it doesn't accept it?

Using: PostgreSQL 9.6 and pgAdmin 4.2

Comment: `ST_Intersects` checks for spatial relation (returns `BOOLEAN`); `ST_Intersection` returns a geometry representing that spatial relation. but then, the intersection of a point with any other geometry is that point...

Comment: @ThingumaBob please make that an answer

Comment: @IanTurton done. bit weird, though...with OPs own answer, however unfitting it might seem. I added a quick disclaimer.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, after a long day one might not see the obvious anymore...:

- `ST_Intersects` checks for the specific spatial relation, and returns
  `BOOLEAN` accordingly
- `ST_Intersection` returns a `GEOMETRY`/`GEOGRAPHY`, representing that spatial
  relation, and is much rather what you are looking for

**However:**

The intersection of a point with any other geometry is exactly that same point...

---

I'm writing this to adress the actual issue in your question, and don't take into account your (actually not quite fitting) answer...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's been a long day. I meant to use st_pointonsurface. Which works just fine. I guess I had to ask the question to realize my mistake.

Comment: `ST_PointOnSurface` doesn't make any sense in the context of the provided code.